# Creation of a Econ-Overflow Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been thinking of creating a Tag exclusively for research based questions as a tool to signal expert questions with the creation of a `econ-overflow` tag.

A tag is important because for some users looking at some questions can be boring and harder research questions are more interesting.

It would be a self regulating tag as others could either comment or flag a post as using the wrong tag and ensure a sort of quality.

This is just an idea though. What do you guys think?

Comment: I like the idea but it would be good to maybe also set up some criteria for questions that qualify, like for example for homework questions, rather than just have it completely self regulating because then when users disagree on the tag who will be the arbiter? Also if it would be just tag without some more guidelines would it even be significantly different from just upvoting?

Comment: I think a simple tag description for when to use it would be fine. I don't expect a lot of homework posters will use the tag. Self-regulation seems mostly okay to me, though muflon's point is well taken. Maybe we put the tag into the ecosystem and see what it ends up being used for?

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry sounds like an experiment